# Decorate requests with authentication headers

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, bearer-token

I have an API that talks to different APIs, most of them are exposed as restful web services. I am using python-requests, for a particular reason in certain environments the APIs are secured and in others, they are not. So I'd like to find a way to include the Authentication based on a condition, probably an env variable or. Is there any way to achieve this goal in a fancy way using decorators or so?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I am authorizing based on a variable set in another file.

There are two files in the same directory ENV.py and py_request.py. I added a few ways I have seen and used to auth commented out.

The contents of `ENV.py` is

---

```
IS_AUTH=True
```

---

The contents of `py_request.py` is

---

```
from .ENV import IS_AUTH
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

is_auth = IS_AUTH
if is_auth:
    res = requests.get('https://yourwebsite.com/', headers={'Authorization': 'access_token myToken'})
    #res = requests.get('https://yourwebsite.com/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password"))
    #res = requests.get('https://yourwebsite.com/', auth=("username", "password"))
else:
    res = requests.get('https://yourwebsite.com/')

print(res.text)
```

---

Comment: is there any other fancy way to do this? I am interacting with many APIs and it would be awesome to use decorator or something like that. If not, that's OK.